# What would be a good equivalent of "Hi everyone! Paul Smith here..."?

Tags: vocabulary

Like when you start off your podcast episode or a YouTube video. I'm interested in the "X here" part. Would something like "*Hallo zusammen! Paul Smith ist da, mit einer weiteren Episode*..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Paul Smith ist da" is more somebody else would say *about* Paul. For example, if you arrive at a party and see Paul, you might say to a friend who came with you, "Schau mal, Paul Smith ist auch da" ("Look, Paul Smith is here as well").

A more natural way of introduction in this context would be something like

> Ich bin Paul Smith

> Mein Name ist Paul Smith

You could probably pontificate about whether you even can be "da" instead of being "hier", because where you are from your perspective is by definition "hier". To say "Ich bin da" has a vibe of a roll call, "Paul Smith?" - "Present!". But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

As a side note, "mit einer weiteren Episode von..." is so obviously literally translated from English that it irks me, at least, a bit as well. I'd rather say something like

> und hier ist eine weitere Folge von...

Whether you use "Folge" or "Episode" is basically a matter of taste.

So, overall I'd suggest something like

> Mein Name ist Paul Smith und hier ist eine weitere Folge von...

Answer (score 2):

"*Hallo zusammen! Hier ist Paul Smith mit einer weiteren Episode...*"

or

"*Hallo zusammen! Hier ist wieder Paul Smith mit einer weiteren Episode...*" (= Paul Smith here again...)

Answer (score 0):

All the YouTubers/Streamers/Tiktokers (or at least the younger generation) keep saying "*Hey Leute!*"

It sounds really annoying though.